# How to display images in pdf using fpdf library?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, opencart2.3

Currently I am working on opencart. And I have to display data in pdf for that I use FPDF.

my function looks like

```
public function exportPDF(){
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'lib/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new fpdf();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

$category_id = $this->request->get['id'];

$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$this->load->model('tool/image');

$temp_data = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductscsv($category_id); 

foreach($temp_data as $data)
{
    if ($data['image']) {
        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($data['image'], 178, 276);
    } else {
        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', 178, 276);
    }
    $data2[] = array(
    'product_id' =>$data['product_id'],
    'model' =>$data['model'],
    'name' =>$data['name'],
    'price' =>$data['price'],
    'image' =>$image,          
    );     
}    
$row = array();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'id',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'model',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'name',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'price',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'image',1);

foreach($data2 as $row)
{  
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
   $pdf->Ln();    
   foreach($row as $column)
    $pdf->Cell(35,50,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();   
}
```

And current output pdf looks like:
[image]

My need is I need to display the images in image column instead of link. how can it make possible. I am new to this, and trying for long time. 
How to use **$pdf->Image();** in the **$data2 array**. How to display images in image column in the pdf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display image in PDF using fpdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664525/display-image-in-pdf-using-fpdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach($data2 as $row)
{  
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
    $pdf->Ln();    
    foreach($row as $key=>$column)
    {  
       if($key == "image"){
             $pdf->Cell(35,50,$this->Image($column,$this->GetX(),$this->GetY()),1);
       }else{           
            $pdf->Cell(35,50,$column,1);         
       } 
    } 
}
```

and also read this : **[reference](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$this->Cell( 35,10, $pdf->Image($image, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY()), 0, 0, 'L', false );
```